# IIS 10 App Pool Crashing - WAS Event 5011 - Issue with VCRUNTIME140.dll

Tags: dll, vbscript, asp-classic, adodb, iis-10

Running IIS 10 on Windows Server 2016 Virtual Machine to run a classic ASP application written in vbscript. The app pool crashes intermittently when I execute an sql statement to insert table in .accdb file from an .xlsx Excel file. Any scripting associated with the .accdb file works fine - once I bring the .xlsx file into the equation is when I have problems. The script is as follows:

```
Set DatabaseConnection = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
DatabaseConnection.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source= C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ORTDEV\QHT2.accdb"
TST0FilePath="C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ORTDEV\TST0ORIG.xlsx"
ssqlinsertresn ="SELECT * INTO TST0 FROM [Excel 12.0; HDR=YES;DATABASE=" & TST0FilePath & "]." & "[TASKRSRC$]"
DatabaseConnection.Execute ssqlinsertresn
```

1. When I run the script, the .xlsx file is closed as well as the .accdb file. I've also tried various excel files to rule out a corrupt .xlsx file.
2. I believe the script is correct. Using IIS 7.5 on Windows 7, I've tested the script on my Laptop without issue. I've also saved the script as a .vbs file and run logged into server as well as my laptop without issue.
3. When it runs on the server through IIS, it may crash the application pool 1 out of 4 times but it's intermittent and not consistent. Even when it crashes, the script will still execute and carry out the sql statement; however, all session variables will clear as expected when the app pool crashes.
4. I've checked for high CPU usage and memory leaks - didn't find anything.
5. I have tracing enabled but no tracing logs appear for this issue.
6. I have errors sent to browser turned on - no errors appear because the script executes as expected.
7. Managed pipeline mode set to classic, although I've tested Integrated as well. .Net CLR version set to v2.0.50727 but I've tested V4.0.30319 too. Enable 32-Bit Applications set to true. Maximum Worker Process Set to 1 since I'm using session variables. Rapid Failure Protection turned on with Maximum of 10 Failures in 5 minutes.
8. I'm testing on a development site and I'm the only one using it.
9. DebugDiag is saying: "Please follow up with vendor Microsoft Corporation for problem resolution concerning the following file: C:\Windows\System32\VCRUNTIME140.dll". Basically, it looks like there is an unhandled exception associated with VCRUNTIME140.dll. I can see the dll installed in the directory, so it's not like it's missing.
10. Event viewer is showing Event ID 5011 - "A process serving application pool 'ORTDEV' suffered a fatal communication error with Windows Process Activation Service."
11. Not much is running on this Virtual Machine. Several SQL Servers are installed, but only 2014 is in use.

Any advice on next steps?

Thx

Keith

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing Application Pool Identity from the default "ApplicationPoolIdentity" to a system account solved the issue.

Comment: Please mark this answer so that it can help others with similar problems

Answer (score 1):

VCRUNTIME140.dll is a dynamic link library file. It works similarly to executable but is only loaded when the software using it needs it. When using excel or other office 365 productions, it will also be used.

VCRUNTIME140.dll is a file used by visual C++ Redistributable for visual studio 2015. Therefore, if any of C++ package constituents are removed accidentally, corrupted or fails to function, the programs may not response and fail. The error you encounter is often encountered by others. The easiest way to fix it is to uninstall and reinstall.

1. Press Win+R and type appwiz.cpl, find entries with names beginning with Microsoft Visual C++2015(or Microsoft Visual C++ 2015-2019) and uninstall.
2. Restart your machine and perform a full scan, clear out any detected threats.
3. Download the official distributive of latest Visual C++2015 version follow this [link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=52685).

Comment: I reinstalled Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 (32 bit) and it did not correct the issue. May need to try 64bit version too.

Comment: You should install the correct version according to your machine.If your machine is 64bit, try 64bit version.

Comment: Well no luck. I removed 2015 and 2017. Restarted and installed 2015 both 32 bit and 64bit. Didn't work so I removed those and installed 
Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015, 2017 and 2019 for 32 bit and 64 bit. Still getting the same error. I suppose it's possible something is wrong with my sql statement but iy works on my laptop without issue. At a loss here.